# How should AngularJS be used when the page structure is user-generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building a web application that is going to have about 6 different "widgets," little boxes performing various functions which can be added to, removed from, and positioned by the user on the page. Each user will have a different set and position of widgets.

My experience is mostly with jQuery, and if I made this the way that I've made applications before, I would generate the widgets using jQuery (`$("<div>", {class:"widget"})`, etc) and add them to the page. I'd love to get away from jQuery, as I know there are lots of other interesting frameworks out there.

From what I've read about AngularJS, it looks more useful if the developer knows the structure of the page when they are creating the application. It separates MVC very well, but the structure of my view is going to entirely depend on the user's preferences. I feel like the big advantages to AngularJS come in its directives, which I don't see how I could get much use out of considering my HTML file is essentially going to be blank at the start.

What would be a good way to structure my application using AngularJS to help me do what I am trying to do? Is there a better framework than AngularJS for this?

Comment: Angular js is the best fit for the scenario which you describe.Refer this document so you will understand to vary view accordingly...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your need, all you need is a web component approach. In Angular it's implemented as a directive. You can create your widgets as a directives and then specify their position on a page using custom elements or element attributes. E.g.:

```
angular.module('widgets', [])
    .directive('my-widget1', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'widget1.html'
        }
    })
    .directive('my-widget2', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div class="simple-widget-2">...</div>'
        }
    });
```

And then in html:

```
<widget1></widget1>
...
<div my-widget2></div>
```

Hope this helps